# Can we operate ms access builtin queries with java

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I want to create queries in `ms access` with the help of `java` program like when we create query in ms access by clicking design query and create our required query can we do this with java program `directly` in detail i want:
create table with and is temporary table can we do this we `ms access` through java

Answer (score 0):

If you have some kind of SQL builder and design tools for use with your java development tools, then you use that.

You not be able to use the Access query designer to build such quires. You could run and use Access code, reports and quires if you are willing to install a full working version of Access on the machine that running your java code. This would require you to use COM automation to launch + create a running instance of Access. You want to make a CLEAR distinction between using the Access front end development system that includes VBA, query designers and all the typical tools designed for a developer. That Access development system can use SQL server, or Oracle or whatever for the database system. Your developer tool is not Access anymore. From your question you ONLY wanting to use the data engine that ships with Access. The default database engine can be used and installed SEPARATE from MS-access the software development tool. So you are failing to distinguish between a development platform like Access, and that of a SEPARATE database engine and system you adopt for your software. Access can also use different database engines. I mean, if you use Visual Studio to create some software, would you NOW attempt to automate and use Visual Studio from Java? (it does not make sense).

So you could “automate” and launch a copy of Access from your code – at which point you could execute the saved query, or pull the SQL from Access into your java code and run it that way. I can’t really recommend this approach since you would be requiring a full version of Access to be installed to run your software – that being the case you would be best to drop java and develop everything in Access.

Even SQL server will not store a bunch of SQL quires that you can then use in java – the exception being “views”, but they don’t allow sql commands such as creating tables, dropping them etc. and those views only appear as tables anyway.

So you need to use and adopt all of the wonderful query tools and designers you have for Java, not attempt to use the ones from say Visual Studio, or a software development tool like Access.

You can most certainly execute SQL commands to create or drop tables in Java, and the database engine could be Oracle, SQL server, or the file based database engine that ships with Access (called ACE).